# Remove duplicate from certain columns with sql query

Tags: mysql

The current query:

```
$query = sprintf("
SELECT compdetails.compname, compdetails.message, specdetails.expirydate, 
specdetails.specday, specdetails.specname, specdetails.specorig, specdetails.specspec, 
specdetails.startdate, complocations.address, complocations.lat, complocations.lng 

FROM compdetails, complocations, specdetails 
WHERE compdetails.compid='%s' 
        
AND specdetails.compid='%s' 
AND complocations.compid='%s'",
```

So:

Compdetails table: 
compname 
message

Specdetails table: 
expirydate 
specday 
specname 
specorig 
specspec 
startdate 
complocations table: 
address 
lat 
lng

What I'm having issues with:

Removing the dupes from this view. See image [image: here]

I only need the following listed once:

1. compname message
   2. expirydate, specday, specname, specorig, specspec, stardate once  each for each address
2. lat,lng per address

Comment: Have you tried GROUP BY with the company name?

Comment: That only gives me 1 address. It's a bizarre request but looking at the picture I only want pizza hut once, every address(and lat lng) once while having D1, D2, D3 specials once as well. That make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT compdetails.compname, compdetails.message, specdetails.expirydate, 
    specdetails.specday, specdetails.specname, specdetails.specorig, specdetails.specspec, 
    specdetails.startdate, complocations.address, complocations.lat, complocations.lng 

FROM compdetails, complocations, specdetails 
WHERE compdetails.compid='%s' 

AND specdetails.compid='%s' 
AND complocations.compid='%s'
GROUP BY compdetails.compname"
```

If you are instead wanting to show all rows but omit certain values on some rows you will have to use logic in your view.